# is a back button really needed?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

im new with andriod and err, im not sure if its really a need for a back button in my activity where there is already a back button on the phone/emulator. I mean since both the back buttons do the same thing which is to go to the previous activity.

So er, can anyone suggest me or give me some advice ? 
would greatly appreciate any suggestions. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the standard back button so I would say there is no need to render your own on screen.  Android users are used to clicking the hardware - or at least system rendered - Back button so they won't go looking for one on screen.

[The menu button is being replaced by the Action Bar](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) but the back button isn't going anywhere.  This is because of the way Android allows one application to launch Activities from another via Intents and so the user always has a standard way to go back to the previous Activity.

Comment: yea, im an iPhone user and thus not used to the back button in andriods; and was wondering if andriods users are better used to clicking the back button on the hardware or in the software itself. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use any back button. There is a nice built-in back button for android device.

Using a back button for android will be too much silly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% need for a back button in your application. This is just a thing that got added to the ActionBar to increase navigation speed.

Comment: The navigation in the ActionBar has a slightly different meaning then the back button. If you are for an example jumping in a chat app through a notification you should see the message you received. Clicking back will bring you back to the last screen you where on maybe the browser or another app. Clicking the actionbar app item should bring you back inside the chat application. Maybe showing the list of contacts. At least for apps that use notifications this is an important difference.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to worry about that by programming! The Back Button Soft or Hardware is giving the same KeyCode. You can find plenty of discussions about the BackButton usage if you search for this in the www.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of a back button in your activity in android. If you are mimicking an iPhone app you may see a back button in it (there is no hardware back button in iPhone). Then if you want to put a back button Go ahead, just a way to waste the activity space

Answer (score 0):

Please don't implement your own back button. This is also a question of **usability**, **identy** and **design**: The back button is an android feature which distinguishes it e.g from apple devices. As it is good praxis to never override the back button (to change its purpose), an android user can always rely on the back button. You don't have to worry: the user nows for sure, where he can go a step back!

Talking about general android usability and design that are great links:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/

http://www.androidpatterns.com/

http://developer.android.com/design/index.html